# How to Remove ODBC Data Source if Driver is Removed

Tags: windows-7, odbc

On my Windows 7 machine, I created an ODBC data source to an Oracle database via the ODBC Data Source Administrator (`c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`). Sometime later, I had to uninstall and reinstall Oracle Client, which resulted in a different Oracle home. So the existing ODBC data sources no longer worked. However, if I try to remove the data source, I get the following error messages:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft ODBC Administrator
---------------------------
The setup routines for the Oracle in ORA112_HOME ODBC driver could not be found.  Please   reinstall the driver.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Then

```
---------------------------
Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed
---------------------------
Errors Found:

Component not found in the registry
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How do I remove these ODBC data source entries?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are defined in the registry under \ODBC\ODBC.INI\ in various places depending on if the definition is

System User:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

32-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

64-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

To delete a data source, you have to delete the data source key under `ODBC.INI` and the entry under `ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources` linking your data source to the driver.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue here. But I found my 32 bit entries under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI
```

Comment: This was already stated in an answer submitted over 2 years ago.

Comment: He has specified ODBCINST.INI was his solution, the original answer specifies ODBC.INI.